# click event for <p:outputLabel> with <p:ajax> inside <p:datatable>

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I created a `<p:datatable>` and I added a column which display a trash icon in each row, and I want delete a row by clicking on the trash icon.

here is my page :

```
<p:column width="4%">
    <p:outputLabel id="dragIcon" styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">
         <p:ajax event="click" update="exploitTable" listener="#{bean.onDelete(item)}"/>
    </p:outputLabel>
</p:column>
```

*item* is the value of `var` attribute of `<p:datatable>`.

But it seems that the *onDelete* method is not called.

Any help ?

Comment: Did you see any error in browser console or your IDE console when you clicked on it `trash` icon?

Comment: Nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem :

I used `<p:commandLink>` instead of `<p:outputLabel>`.

```
<p:column width="3%">
    <p:commandLink id="delete" styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" actionListener="#{listeExploitant.onDelete(exploitant)}" update="exploitTable"/>
</p:column>
```